# Why evaluate self._initial_state when training RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In the RNN tutorial [ptd_word_lm.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). When training the RNN using run_epoch, why is it necessary to evaluate self._initial_state?

```
def run_epoch(session, m, data, eval_op, verbose=False):
  """Runs the model on the given data."""
  epoch_size = ((len(data) // m.batch_size) - 1) // m.num_steps
  start_time = time.time()
  costs = 0.0
  iters = 0
  state = m.initial_state.eval()
  for step, (x, y) in enumerate(reader.ptb_iterator(data, m.batch_size,
                                                    m.num_steps)):
    cost, state, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op],
                                 {m.input_data: x,
                                  m.targets: y,
                                  m.initial_state: state})
    costs += cost
    iters += m.num_steps

    if verbose and step % (epoch_size // 10) == 10:
      print("%.3f perplexity: %.3f speed: %.0f wps" %
            (step * 1.0 / epoch_size, np.exp(costs / iters),
             iters * m.batch_size / (time.time() - start_time)))

  return np.exp(costs / iters)
```

The initial state is defined as following and is never changed during training.

```
self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PTB example, the sentences are concatenated and split into batches (of size batch_size x num_steps). After each batch, the last state of the RNN is passed as the initial state of the next batch. This effectively allows you to train the RNN as if it was one very long chain over the entire PTB corpus (and this explain why model.final_state is evaluated and why the state is passed into m.initial_state in the feed_dict). So you see that the initial_state actual **does** change at every step.

At the very beginning of an epoch, we have no previous state to pass as the initial_state and so use all zeros, represented by state = m.initial_state.eval(). Perhaps it would be less confusing if there was another property called m.zero_state that you evaluated to get this initial state. You could, for example, also use a numpy array of zeros of the appropriate size and this would work just fine too. The eval is just a convenient way to get a tensor or zeros of the appropriate size.

Hope this makes sense!